# Surface Area of Solid

Tags: surfaces

The figure shows (Can't show the picture because I don't have) A solid consisting of a pyramid of a height $28\mathrm{cm}$ fastened to a cuboid of height $40\mathrm{cm}$ and a square base of sides $30\mathrm{cm}$ each. Find the total surface area of the solid.

Can anyone help me find the formula for the question? I think there is no need for picture nor the question but anyway...

Comment: sorry for the tag i did not have enough reputation for a new tag as I am new here. And i also don't have a picture as i said in the question. Please tell me the formula.
Thanks

Comment: The base of the pyramid is 30 x 30? What is the difficulty? How many rectangular faces do you have? What is the area of a rectangle? How many triangular faces do you have? What is the area of a triangle?

Comment: Your entire solid has 9 sides, 5 from the cuboid and 4 from the pyramid (the side that they share is not on the surface anymore). You need to add up the areas of these 9 sides.

Comment: Thank you @Prakhar Nagpal for the edits you made to the question :)